# Для чего нужны <? extends> и <? super> как параметры метода

Tags: java, generics, java-stream, lambda, функциональное-программирование

Есть функция:

```
<R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper);
```

Она производит операции над элементами `Stream` и возвращает `Stream` с результирующими элементами. На вход мы подаем реализацию функционального интерфейса, то есть метода:

```
R apply(T t);
```

Я это и делаю:

```
.map(User::getName)
```

То есть, если я правильно понимаю, вместо `T` *подставляется* тип `User`, вместо `R` тип `String`. Тогда объясните , для чего вообще нужно `super` и `extends` в параметрах?

Я понимаю, что `super T` означает: "`T` или любой его суперкласс", `extends R` означает "`R` или любой его подкласс"?

В чем преимущество `T` по сравнению с `super T`, где это можно использовать? С обычным методом все понятно (можем передать экземпляр любого суперкласса как параметр), а вот с параметром типа функционального интерфейса не очень.

Мы ведь просто передаем реализацию с конкретными `T(User)` и `R(String)`, где нам тогда могут пригодится подклассы и суперклассы?

Comment: это называется [ковариантность и контравариантность](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B8_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)) в месте использования (use-site variance, бывает еще declaration-site, при объявлении типа) и позволяет передавать в `map` не только `Function<User, String>`, но и `Function<предок_User, наследник_String>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java generics построены на идеи PECS (production - extends; consumer - super), т.е. производитель определяет верхние границы, а потребитель определяет нижние границы.

Потом в `Function` где `T` - входные данные, а `R` - выходные данные. Его часто называют отображением, так как входные данные "отображаются" в выходные. Рассмотрим пример:

```
Function<String, Integer> fun = (str) ->
            Integer.parseInt(str);
    System.out.println(fun.apply("234"));
```

Здесь входной должна быть строчкой, а в выходе мы получим Integer.  Получается в вашем варианте входной был `User`, а выходе мы должны получить имя юзера.

Answer (score 4):

Как раз таки наоборот, преимущество типа `? super T` по сравнению с `T` состоит в том, что в первом случае на вход функции можно посылать объекты разных типов, которые либо `T` либо являются суперкласом `T`. То есть мы не можем сказать, что тип параметра `T`. А также, мы не можем посылать объекты наследники `T`, в качестве параметра функции. Во втором случае тип `T` определен однозначно по иерархии, несмотря на то, что он является обобщенным типом, не принимаются наследники `T` и он не является наследником `T`.