# Про обобщения (generics)

Tags: java, generics, wildcards

Чем такой формат объявления метода

```java
<T extends Number> double sum(Collection<T> c ) {...}
```

отличен от

```java
double sum2(Collection<? extends Number> c ) {...}
```

если в итоге результат не отличается ?
что лучше использовать и почему ?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176594/when-to-use-generic-methods-and-when-to-use-wild-card

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Для чего нужны <? extends> и <? super> как параметры метода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/848287/%d0%94%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b-extends-%d0%b8-super-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Это две принципиально разные вещи. В первом случае, ты говоришь, что в  следующем блоке у тебя будет общий дженерик (тип который будет подставляться в зависимости от обращения).

```
    class OurClass<T> {
        void someFun(T a, T b) {
            System.out.println(a + b);
        }
    }
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OurClass<String> stringObject = new OurClass<>();
        OurClass<Int> intObject = new OurClass<>();
        stringObject.someFun("asd", "qwe"); //вывод asdqwe
        intObject.someFun(1,2); //вывод 12
    }
}
```

Во втором же, просто обозначаешь с каким типом данных будет работать Collection потому что в ее реализации как раз и используются дженерики.

Update из комментариев:
Ок. Когда мы что-то пишем в коде, то мы обозначаем свои намерения. Если мы объявляем класс, а внутри него просто делаем только статическую переменную, то это выглядит странно и не понятно. Так же и с дженериками. Если мы хотим сказать, что в этом месте будет использоваться общий для данных тип, то мы используем обобщение. Если же мы хотим просто определить тип, который используется в конкретной реализации, то делаем именно это. Отсюда и выбор того, что лучше.

Comment: но в первом блоке <T extends Number> и  это не как в примере -   void someFun(T a, T b) т.е. вариант просто  stringObject.someFun("asd", "qwe"); //вывод asdqwe  - не пройдет из-за <T extends Number> - тип String не подойдет из-за ограничения сверху - Number или нет ?

Comment: и речь про обобщённые методы `<T extends Number> double sum(Collection<T> c ){...}` а не про класс (хотя возможно это и не важно). речь про конкретный этот случай

Comment: @user452992 Ок. Когда мы что-то пишем в коде, то мы обозначаем свои намерения. Если мы объявляем класс, а внутри него просто делаем только статическкую переменную, то это выглядит странно и не понятно. Так же и с дженертками. Если м хотим сказать, что в этом месте будет использоваться общий для данных тип, то мы используем обобщение. Если же мы хотим просто определить тип, который используется в конкретной реализации, то делаем именно это. Отсюда и выбор того, что лучше.

Comment: Ок. Но по результату (в этом примере) -  это одно и тоже ? Разница лишь в "обозначении намерений" ?

Comment: В данном случае да, это будет одно и тоже. В программировании всегда одну и туже задачу можно решить разными способами. И надо выбирать тот, который наиболее подходит для наших намерений. ИМХО. И в комментарии к твоему вопросу хорошая ссылка, там подробно разбирается твой вопрос.

Comment: да, ссылка хорошая . В целом,  картина прояснилась